# Proguard outjar throwing new errors

Tags: java, jar, proguard, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate a jar file with proguard through its gui.
My project uses gradle, but I couldn't make it work, I didn't find tutorials and I don't understand much about gradle, so the documentation is difficult for me to understand.

This is my proguard config:

```
-injars 'build\libs\noah-viewer-gradle-0.3.jar'
-outjars 'build\libs\noah-viewer-gradle-obfuscated.jar'

-libraryjars 'D:\Programas\jdk-17\jmods\java.base.jmod'
-libraryjars 'D:\Programas\jdk-17\jmods\java.naming.jmod'
-libraryjars 'D:\Programas\jdk-17\lib\jrt-fs.jar'

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn sun.media.jai.**
-dontwarn com.sun.**
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn org.dcm4che3.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main' methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver

# Also keep - Swing UI L&F. Keep all extensions of javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI,
# along with the special 'createUI' method.
-keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
    public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent);
}

# Keep - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

But the outjar file is throwing a new error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: SwigDirector_Command_getName
        at org.itk.simple.SimpleITKJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
        at org.itk.simple.SimpleITKJNI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.webkriativa.noahviewer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

This is the proguard log (with -dontwarn): https://pastecode.io/s/tigv6fzj
And this is the proguard log (removing de -dontwarn): https://pastecode.io/s/h6icq6pe

How could i fix this error? Is this a libraryjars error?
Or perhaps a recommendation for easier-to-use software?
Maybe instructions or a good tutorial for gradle configuration...

Thanks!